# How can I set a string saved in a variable as the selected item in a combobox

Tags: php, html

I have a combobox filled with SQL data. When I create a variable (this variable is always the same as the SQL data inside the combobox) and I click select, I want the combobox to select the data inside it with the same value as the variable.

Is this possible?

This is needed to create an update event.
This is what have so far:

```
<select id="basis" name="basisp" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($n4); ?>">
    <?php foreach($result as $pers): ?>
    <option value="<?= $pers['naam']; ?>"><?= $pers['naam']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

$n4 is the variable, the code above doesnt work.

Comment: Please don't repost.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *selected* keyword to select a specific item in your combobox:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

So in your case maybe:

```
<select id="basis" name="basisp" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($n4); ?>">
    <?php foreach($result as $pers): ?>
    <option value="<?= $pers['naam']; ?>"<?= if($pers['naam']==$n4) { echo ' selected'; } ?>><?= $pers['naam']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thats not what I asked, Im talking about data from a database

Comment: I want data from a variable